# Google Places Autocomplete - How to show only country names

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, filtering, google-places-api, search-box

I want the users to see only the country names when they type on the search box. Is it possible?

[image]

I've tried this (doesn't work):

```
var options = {
    types: [('regions')]
};

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, options);
```

Comment: Maybe you should use your own autocomplete, with just countries.  Maybe like [this](http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector)?

Answer (score 2):

Google lets you to use some properties for getting the data like you want.You can set to it language and anything else.
Here is a link,which will help you.
http://www.w3docs.com/learn-javascript/places-autocomplete.html